# Is field in Salesforce considered as metadata ? Can I deploy via Sfdx

Tags: metadata, sfdx-plugin

Want to create a mass field on custom object. Is field in Salesforce considered metadata.xml

Can I deploy them via sfdc

Answer (score 3):

Yes, fields on SObjects (and Custom Settings, and Custom Metadata Types) are metadata and can be deployed using the Salesforce CLI.

Deploying an individual field would look like
`sfdx force:source:deploy -m CustomField:MySobject__c.MyField__c`

The usual warnings about Field Level Security not being carried over to the new org still applies.

Creating the field metadata itself is still something I'd do declaratively (though the web UI, either in a sandbox or a scratch org), but you can do it programmatically if you're determined enough to go that route. If you create a field through the web ui, you can fetch it using sfdx too (just use `force:source:retrieve` instead of `force:source:deploy`).